# SetColorEffect() is not working in Google Nexus 7 version 2

Tags: android, colors, camera

Recently I bought a Nexus 7 version 2 and tested my application. All are working except the Camera modules.

Actually, I got no problem in taking a photo but the problem happened in setColorEffect(). As you know this function is to set the color effect to the camera and surfaceview should reflect this change.

I have no doubt you are using below functions to set the color effect:

```
                Camera.Parameters _param = mCamera.getParameters();

                if (isSupported(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO, _param.getSupportedColorEffects())) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "color effect is supported...");
                    _param.setColorEffect(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
                    _param.setJpegQuality(90);

                    //_param.set("effect", "mono"); // KEY_EFFECT
                    mCamera.setParameters(_param);
                }
```

I put above code in surfaceChanged() and other places recommended here but it's not working and even I got no errors and no exceptions. I also fired surfaceChanged() function by force after changing the preview size. Below is surfaceChanged() function:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
    return;
}

try {
    lCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    lCamera.startPreview();
}
```

}

Strangely, Scene Mode change was working.

Before testing the Nexus 7 2, I tested my application and above code under Galaxy S3 and it's working perfectly.

I have tested about 3-4 camera examples from the internet including Google provided, all were NOT working. (FYI: Nexus 7 version 2 is providing about 9 color effects.)

Anyone any idea?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Nop. not yet. Almost I've given up.